# js, object's state monitoring

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sometimes on server I have situation when it's necessary to get some data from object in the time it is being changed by another piece of code. It's important to have up to date object state during object viewing. I solved this issue by the code like this :

```
var Obj1={}
Obj1.actual=false;

//asynk part that modifies object
function modify_func(){
    Obj1.actual=false;
    //modifying operations
    Obj1.actual=true;
}

//asynk part that gets object state
function view_func(){
    if(Obj1.actual){
        //operations
            ...
        return;
    }
    //if not actual
    var timer=setInterval(function(){
        if(Obj1.actual){
            //operations
            ...
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    },1000)
}
```

this two functions can be awakened in any time.
However, I don't really think it was good idea to use setInterval and actuality field.
Is there some better solution of this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest implementing an event listener for this, in stead. So register any callback that wants to know about the changes, and call those callbacks after the changes were made.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden, I can't put view_func to cb,because it's located in separate request handler on server, and can be executed 1000 times whereas modify_func only 10 for example, or vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise` for this case. How it has to be structured depends on your actual use-case.

A setup could look like this:

```
Obj1 = {};

//async part that modifies object
function modify_func() {

  //at this point you might need to check if modifying is already in progress.

  Obj1._modifying = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //modifying operations

    delete Obj1._modifying;
    resolve();
  });
}

function view_func() {
  if (Obj1._modifying) {
    Obj1._modifying.then(_view_fun_internal);
  } else {
    _view_fun_internal();
  }

}

function _view_fun_internal() {
  //do some stuff on the ready object
}
```

But be award that this will only work well if the collecting of the data in `_view_fun_internal` is sync.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!  It's great idea to use promise in such way.