# Can I use a global variable to synchronize request in node express?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, synchronization

I want to check if a request path is used for the first time.

Do nodejs monothreaded model insure following code will work the way it is intended ? Is there any possible case where this code could send "**you are the first one**" more than once ?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let FIRST = true

app.get("/", function(req, res) {   
    res.send("you are "+(FIRST?'':'not')+" the first one")
    FIRST = false       
});

app.listen(8080, function(){});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find useful next question related to [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228034/js-objects-state-monitoring) in node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possible case where this code could send "you are the first one" more than once ?

No.  Since there is no async code inside that request handler, it will execute synchronously and the single threaded nature of node.js will ensure that nothing else modifies `FIRST` while this request handler is using it.

Actually, the way your code is written, it will never show that the user is the first user because you always set `FIRST` to false before using it in your `res.send()`.

Comment: Is res.send() not asynchronous ?

Comment: @AliceOualouest - It is, but `FIRST` has already been used before it's called and there's no code in this function after `res.send()` so it does not matter to this question.

Comment: Original question was modified to set `FIRST` after `res.send()`.

Comment: @AliceOualouest - The way the question has been modified, there's still no chance for another request handler to get called between the call to `res.send()` and the setting of the FIRST variable.  While `res.send()` may do the actually sending of the response in the background asynchronously after `res.send()` returns, that doesn't affect your code here because you aren't setting the value of FIRST in some asynchronous callback.  You're setting it synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, but you need to move the `FIRST` condition after the `res.send`

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {   
    res.send("you are "+(FIRST?'':'not')+" the first one")
    if (FIRST){
        FIRST = false       
    }
});
```

Do not forget, that if your process exited, and launched again, the next user will think that he is first.
If you want to show this message ONLY to the real first user you should use a storage to keep it outside of RAM memory. The most easiest way, is to save it to a text file.

[Learn more about NodeJS File System Object](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: same comment, here, what about res.send beeing asynchronous ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work as you are coding. As you have no async code inside that request handler, that is why it will execute as synchronous way.

Using your code it will never show that the current user is FIRST user , as in your code you are setting FIRST to false before res.send()

Just move the IF condition after the res.send(), You can check the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let FIRST = true

app.get("/", function(req, res) {   
  res.send("you are "+(FIRST?'':'not')+" the first one")
  if (FIRST){
    FIRST = false       
  }
});

app.listen(8080, function(){});
```

Comment: You are right for the "first" message never displaying. But using your solution, it seems to me that, res.send beeing asynchronous, two requests can be seen as "first".

Comment: What about res.send beeing asynchronous ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful next question related to **synchronization** in Node.js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228034/js-objects-state-monitoring).

There are described problem with shared object modification.